# Python - How to export each item in a list to individual text file

Tags: python, loops, csv, web-scraping, output

I have a `csv` file of a couple dozen web pages that I am trying to loop over.

The goal is to get the text from the web page, take out the html markup (using `html2text`), and then save the clean text as a `.txt` file.  My idea was to save the clean text of each webpage as an item in the list, then export each item in the list to a txt file.

I can get the program to loop over the urls and take out the html, but saving to individual txt files keeps throwing an error.  Can anyone give me some ideas on how to do this?

Code:

```
from stripogram import html2text
import urllib
import csv

text_list = []
urls = csv.reader(open('web_links2.csv'))

for url in urls:
    response = urllib.urlopen(url[0])
    html = response.read()
    text = html2text(html)
    text_list.append(text)

print text_list

for item in text_list:
    f = open('c:\users\jacob\documents\txt_files\%s.txt'%(item,), 'w')
    f.write(item)
    f.close
```

Comment: What is the error being thrown, and where is it occurring?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you might not want to add the full item to the filename since the item is all the html of a webpage. In your case I'd either add some logic to give it a neat website name or just use an index so you can iterate over this.

Also the file path definition should be different, try to use double quotes and \ instead of .
You might want to do something like this:

```
i = 0
for item in text_list:
    i += 1
    #also use format instead of the %s
    f = open("c:\\users\\jacob\\documents\\txt_files\\{0}.txt".format(i), 'w')
    f.write(item)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the same value (`item`) for both the names of the files and their contents, so unless these files are single words, you are likely generating illegal file names.

Plus, in order to call `close`, you need to supply the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you are not escaping the `t` use raw string `r`:

```
open(r'c:\users\jacob\documents\txt_files\%s.txt'%(item,), 'w')
```

`\t` is tab so use raw string as in the example, double `\\` or forward slashes `/` in your file path.

```
In [11]: s = "\txt_files"

In [12]: print(s)
    xt_files

In [13]: s = r"\txt_files"

In [14]: print(s)
\txt_files


f.close <- missing parens to call the method
```

Use with to open you file and things like forgetting to call close will not be an issue:

```
with open(r'c:\users\jacob\documents\txt_files\%s.txt'%(item,), 'w') as f: # closes your files automatically
    f.write(item)
```